# Query about Java Heap space String Object Storage

Tags: java, string

I know that

```
String s1 = "test";
String s2 = new String("test");
System.out.println(s1==s2);  // false
```

in above snippet "test" String Object is created inside the String pool in java (s1 will be passed its reference) 
and a new String Object will be created in the heap space of the memory (s2 will be in heap sapce).

so **will s2 String object be referring to the String pool's "test" String object internally or s2 keeps an altogether different "test" String Object in memory** ?

**what will be the effect if we somehow "test" String Object in String constant pool is removed ? will s2 still be having the value "test" ?**

I know this topic has been touched a lot but none of the previous answers which i checked clarifies it.

please mention any sources if that has a better explanation.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: In [the Java 8 source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java/#151), the `String(String)` constructor reuses the `value` field from the parameter.

Comment: Just wondering: why would you care? One should avoid comparing strings with ==; so again ... what is the actual problem you intent to solve?

Comment: @AndyTurner I have an additional question - String stores a char[]-array internally. If the constructor String(String) is called, there is a reference to the char[]-array stored in the new string-instance. If I understand this the right way, s1 and s2 as described in the question are different instances, but internally the char[]-array would be the same on the heap. Or am I wrong with this?

Comment: @Supahupe that is exactly what I am saying in my answer below.

Comment: Thanks, I was not sure at first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [the Java 8 source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java/#151), the `String(String)` constructor reuses the `value` field from the parameter.

Note that `value` is a `char[]`, though, so the two string instances use the same underlying array, but `s2` is not using the `"test"` itself internally, since that is a `String`, not a `char[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link to the Article by Corey McGlone

http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200409/Journal200409.jsp#a1

Comment: You should avoid Link-only answers because they are not useful if the link dies. Consider editing your answer to include the relevant details from the linked article.